# How to run pre-commit on separate folders?

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/), and I have a repository with two folders:

```
.
├── backend
│   └── (backend files)
├── frontend
│   └── (frontend files)
└── .pre-commit-config.yaml
```

Each folder has a Dockerfile and is independent from the other.

This is my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: go-docker
        name: go
        language: docker_image
        entry: backend:latest go fmt
        files: backend/

      - id: prettier-docker
        name: prettier
        language: docker_image
        entry: frontend:latest npm run format
        files: frontend/
```

I want to run pre-commit on both folders with Docker, but I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /src/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

According to the pre-commit documentation: `pre-commit will automatically mount the repository source as a volume using -v $PWD:/src:rw,Z and set the working directory using --workdir /src.`

So the issue seems to be that the `frontend` folder is located at `src/frontend` but the path that pre-commit uses is just `src`.

I tried `cd frontend` before the Docker command with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're correct that you need to `cd`, but you'll need to do that inside of docker

for example:

```yaml
      - id: prettier-docker
        name: prettier
        language: docker_image
        entry: frontend:latest bash -c 'cd frontend && npm run format'
        files: frontend/
```

if I recall correctly you'll want `pass_filenames: false` as well

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Yes, I'll pass `pass_filenames: false` too, I removed it for the sake of simplicity.